# Getting locations of user's friends with Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

Is it possible to get the nearby locations of a user's friends, or, when searching for nearby venues, determine how many friends are present at each of the venues?

In other words, I would like to list all nearby venues along with a count of friends here now. Can this be done without making venue detail calls on all of the venues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friend information is not currently accessible via the /venues/search endpoint -- only the total number of users at the venue.

As you mentioned, you can call the /venues/VENUE_ID/herenow endpoint to get more information (including friend vs. non-friend) breakdowns for the returned venues.

You can, alternatively, make a single call to /checkins/recent and combine the data about current friend location with /venues/search results.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed. By the way, does Foursquare use any special method for determining who is "hereNow", or is it simply based on time since check in?

Comment: 3 hours or if they check-in elsewhere. Always subject to tweaking though